# PhD from university where I did my bachelor's degree or master's degree?

Tags: university

I currently live in New Zealand an I'm studying animal science. I got my bachelor of science in New Zealand (from Massey) and my masters from Melbourne University.

Do you think it is strange if I go back to New Zealand to the same University to do my PhD? I've heard that it is good to go to different Universities for all your degrees to show that you are "open-minded", but if I have already gone to two different universities for my bachelors and masters, am I already showing that I am "open-minded"?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 2):

Well if the topic or material is “local” to that university then it seems logical.

If you are going to study, for example, the effects of tourism on the breeding habits of koala bears then enrolling in the University of Wisconsin or Oxford or Cambridge may not be too helpful.

You should enrol at a Uni that has the course that you want, with the facilities you need and the environment you like - both for work and relaxation. It does not help, if you are happy in the stcks to be in a high-rise neither does moving to the sticks suit a city-dweller...

I am in an establishment where 1 metre of snow is common in winter and some new colleagues find winter just too much and leave...

Answer (score 1):

I think that the main reason for going to a different university is that you may have already learned just about everything that the current/past one has to teach you. By moving you will see new perspectives. It isn't that you have an open mind, it is that you may (hopefully *will*) be introduced to new ideas.

That may not be the case in especially large universities with large faculties. And it may be less important also, if the place you already are has the experts (and research) that you need to work with. But finding ways to stretch your mind and experiences is normally good.

New Zealand is itself a rather small place. Australia is a bit bigger, of course. I don't know how much "academic inbreeding" there is between the two. Europe or the US have a lot of diversity. But if the work you want to do is well done in a small place it should be fine.